# C++/C Language Independent Memory Allocation

Tags: c++, c, memory-management

Is it common practice to define a macro that translates to new for C++ and malloc for C?
(And an equivalent delete/free macro)

Comment: C _or_ C++? Pick one. Anyway, `new` and `malloc` are already portable. What are you looking for?

Comment: No, it is not common, it is bad because it obscures code. Use `new` for C++ and `malloc` for C. Portability is *platform* independance (or  `#ifdef` blocks for platform specific code).

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are trying to achieve? Are you looking to write code that can run on 32 and 64-bit Windows, Linux, IBM OS/400 (AS/400 architecture), Sun Solaris, OSE Delta, Symbian OS as well as 8-bit microcontrollers and everything in between? Or a smaller selection of machines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is NOT possible to make `malloc` behave exactly like `new` (without much trickery, and some of the details in this will be VERY tricky to achieve), because `new` oversees the construction of the object.

Making `malloc` turn into `new` is a little easier, since there is nothing "special" about what `malloc` does.

If you want code that is portable, don't write it in C++ [if your concern is the availability of C++ or some such], use C (it is perfectly possible to use C++ to call C functions in a reasonably portable way, the other way around is much harder). But if you are writing in C++, then use `new`, not `malloc`.

Note of course that if you have a C++ compiler, and your environment doesn't support `new` for some reason (e.g. using C++ code in Windows XP kernel mode drivers, like what I used work withat at one point [no, it wasn't my idea, and I didn't implement it, I just worked in the project in general]) it is possible to implement an operator `new` that is based on `malloc` or some other basic "give me some memory" type function [there is no `malloc` in a Windows kernel driver either, but there are ways to allocate memory, of course].

Of course, it's IMPORTANT to take into account what you are actually trying to achieve - portability is only really useful if you have some sort of code that in itself is meaningful to run on many platforms, and it's often much easier to NOT make code overly portable - it can really make the code quite complex to work with.

Edit: I have to add that I'm not sure I understand why C++ would be a difficulty in portability as long as we are talking source code can be compiled for different machines. If you are using C++ to distribute libraries, it gets a bit more tricky, as there are parts of C++ that aren't well defined in binary code. But that's a special case, and I'm far from convinced that should be a guiding criteria for what language you write in.

Comment: If you are not using classes, then why are you worried about C++ at all. Use C. Microsoft's compiler may not be the most standards compliant, but but it compiles C as well as C++. C++ is a pretty pointless language if you don't use classes [although it does add a few other things, the power in C++ comes from using classes]. I would suggest that you study C++ and understand what it's strengths and weaknesses are.

Comment: No, C doesn't have references - it's not part of the language - use pointers instead (the actual code generated from references and pointers are essentially the same, it's just a bit of "syntactic sugar" that makes references look different in the code)

Answer (score 6):

> Is it common practice to define a macro that translates to new for C++ and malloc for C? (And an equivalent delete/free macro)

No.

> I was wondering if such a thing is common practice because I have never seen it in use in any programs but I can't think of any reason why it would be a bad thing to do

C is not C++. C++ is not C. There's absolutely no reason to do it.

Answer (score 3):

No. The semantics of `new` and `malloc` are different: `malloc` allocates memory; `new` allocates memory and calls the constructor.